# Why does my code to insert into linked list fail on the 3rd item?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to write functions to add value at the nth position and delete also from nth position. When I test my insert function it seems to work well, but then it gets stuck when I try to add a value in the third position.

When I comment it out, the code works well. Why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Node Struct
struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};

struct Node *head;  // Global head of the struct

//Function to create New Node with Data and return it
struct Node* NewNode (int data){
    struct Node* temp=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    temp->data=data;
    temp->next=NULL;
    return temp;

}
// Function to add new value in nth Position
void AddN(int data,int n){
    struct Node* temp = NewNode(data);
    struct Node *temp1= head;
    if(n==1){
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;
    }
    else{
        for(int i=0;i=n-2;i++){
            temp1=head->next;
        }
        temp->next=temp1->next;
        temp1->next=temp;
    }
}

void Print(){
    struct Node* tempHead=head;
    while(tempHead != NULL){
        printf("%d ", tempHead->data);
        tempHead = tempHead->next;
    }
}

void main(){
    head=NULL; //Empty List
    AddN(1,1); //List: 1
    AddN(2,2); //List: 1 2
    //AddN(3,3); //List: 1 2 (3) ( Doesn't work)
    AddN(4,1); //List: 4 1 2 
    AddN(5,2); //List: 4 5 1 2 
    Print();
}
```

Comment: `for(int i=0;i=n-2;i++){
            temp1=head->next;
        }` is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious error is the for loop:

```
for(int i=0;i=n-2;i++)
```

This expression, `i=n-2` doesn't check for equality but set the value n-2 to i. Perhaps i < n-2 should be there?

And in the body of the for loop this assignment `temp1=head->next;` also does nothing constructive.

After the for loop the value of pointer `temp1` could be NULL, depending on the index passed to the function. The following line `temp->next=temp1->next;` dereferences that pointer causing undefined behavior.

Another problem is that you don't check if head is NULL if you insert a node with an index that is larger than 1.

Comment: yes it's a shame typo, would you mind if you clarify what did you mean by  `temp1=head->next;` does nothing constructive?

Comment: @saYco Because it just assigns the same value to temp1 over and over again in the loop.